# The following space is Separable or not?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Determine whether the space of step functions defined on [0,1] on uniform norm, is separable or not? Explain in details.

I guess it is not separable, but I do not have a nice argument to show it.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Hint: Look at the distance between the functions $\{f_t := \chi_{[0,t]}$ for $t\in [0,1]\}$.

Comment: I didn't get it. distance between function is either 0 or 1.right?

Comment: What does "uniform norm" mean?

Comment: Exactly, if $t\neq s$, then the distance is 1. Now think about whether such a space can be separable. @bof: It is likely he means the supremum norm.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. Use Prahlad's idea from the comments. If you do not see, what this helps you, recall the following:

> **Lemma**. *Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, if there is some uncountable $A \subseteq X$ and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $d(x,y) \ge \epsilon$ for every two distinct $x,y \in A$, then $X$ is not seperable.*

*Proof (sketch)*. Let $D$ be any countable subset of $X$, if $D$ were dense, then for $a \in A$, there were an $x_a \in D$ such that $d(a,x_a) < \frac{\epsilon}2$. Now $A \to D$, $a \mapsto x_a$ is one-to-one, but $A$ is uncoutable.